# How to parameterize the sort filter using tinkerpop gremlin / frames?

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop-frames

I want to sort my results using a given fieldname:

```
@GremlinGroovy(value = "it.in('HAS_USER').sort{fieldName}._()[skip..limit]")
public Iterable<TPUser> getUsersInOrder(@GremlinParam("fieldName") String fieldName, @GremlinParam("skip") int skip, @GremlinParam("limit") int limit);
```

Unfortunately the results for *getUsersInOrder("it.username", 0, 5)* are not sorted as expected. When i replace fieldName in the gremlin code with "it.username" the results are ordered by the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the sort method is part of groovy and not gremlin. Instead the order method can be used to sort entries:

```
@GremlinGroovy(value = "it.in('HAS_USER').order({ it.b.getProperty(fieldName) <=> it.a.getProperty(fieldName) })[skip..limit]")
public Iterable<TPUser> getUsersInOrder(@GremlinParam("fieldName") String fieldName, @GremlinParam("skip") int skip, @GremlinParam("limit") int limit);
```

Comment: I have not yet figured out how to parameterize the sortorder.